# How to see the source data difference between FeatureLayers

Tags: geotools

I have 2 different FeatureLayers, one from the Postgis database (table name ATZ) and one from the SHAPE file (filename = ATZ.shp).

When I search for features with a bounding box filter I get several features. In my Set for the selected features they are all named ATZ.xxyy (xxyy = fid) regardless if the object is from the shape file or from the database table.

How do I know from which source the selected features are from?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to be definitive but if it's important to know the source of a feature then you would need to make a note of which `DataStore` it came from when you run the searches.

`SimpleFeatureSource` has a `getDataStore()` method if you only have sources to hand.